# Schedule Task Run Not Working In Laravel Window 10

Tags: laravel, cron, task, scheduling, schedule

everyone
I am doing about schedule of laravel. I setup as following:

**Case 1**: everyMinute(): php artisan schedule:run => Running scheduled command:
"D:\Program\Xampp\php\php.exe" "artisan" demo:cron > "NUL" 2>&1

**Case 2**: everyFiveMinutes() or everyMinute()->daily(): php artisan schedule:run => No scheduled commands are ready to run.

**Case 3**: everyTwoMinutes() => php artisan schedule:run => Running scheduled command: "D:\Program\Xampp\php\php.exe" "artisan" demo:cron > "NUL" 2>&1 => But the schedule runs immediately, not 2 minutes

**I wondered where I went wrong. And can be edited to be able to run the Schedule as follows: Every 5 minutes, insert 1 more user into the DB ? I run Window 10, Laravel 7.x**

**But you can guide me both in ubutu 18 or 20**

This is my code:

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\DemoCron::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('demo:cron')->everyTwoMinutes();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}

class DemoCron extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'demo:cron';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {

        DB::table('users')->insert(['name'=>'hello new','email'=>'hoangpm'.rand() ,'password'=>'123']);
        $this->info('Demo:Cron Cummand Run successfully!');
    }
}
```